# MVC 3 Razor view BeginForm form post not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

When cliking the button form post is not working. Guys any idead ?

**Razor VIew**

```
<div id="contactform">
    <h3>
        Contact Form</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("contacts", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()


        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </li>
                <li>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)
                </li>
                <li>

                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type="button" value="contacts"/>
        </fieldset>

    }
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display (Name="Name")]  
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display (Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    [Display (Name="Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]   
    public string Message { get; set; }


}
```

**Home Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult contacts(ContactModel contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }


    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please define "post is not working": is your action not being hit? What response code do you get? Do you see the request in your browser's dev consolse/firebug/fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **submit** your data to the server you need a [submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html) button in order to the browser (if you are not posting with javascript) sends your data to the server

So change:

```
<input type="button" value="contacts"/>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" value="contacts"/>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Alternately, use `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`.